# GitKraken erro para fazer o push

Tags: git

Meu **GitKraken** *estava* funcionando corretamente, porém, desde ontem **não** consigo fazer o `push` e *sempre* acontece esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Baixou o Git via HTTP? É um repositório privado? Pode dar mais detalhes? Não dá pra ter certeza se é um BUG ou se é problema em algum repositório.

Answer (score 2):

Este erro não está necessariamente ligado ao Git.

Ocorreu que ao acessar o endereço do repositório Git, o servidor retornou para você o erro **HTTP 308** (*308 Permanent Redirect*). Se fomos levar ao pé da letra o significado deste código 308, ocorre que algum endereço do servidor mudou **permanentemente** para um outro endereço.

A maioria dos navegadores lida bem com isto e de forma transparente para o usuário, pois é esperado que com este erro seja fornecido um cabeçalho `Location` no response, com o novo endereço no qual o navegador saberá para onde mandar a requisição.

Contudo, acho que o GitKraken não soube fazer este redirecionamento para você e está acusando este erro. Veja se existe algum bug reportado ao GitKraken sobre isto e verifique o endereço do seu repositório Git, confirmando se não houve alguma mudança neste sentido.

Comment: Caro Dherik eu concordo contigo sobre a explicação do HTTP, mas isso não resolve o problema em si, pode ser algum serviço que esta se comunicando, tem GIT que usa HTTP também, por isso o problema nem pode ser no GitKraken, pode ser em um repositório privado, não tem como ter certeza da forma que a pergunta esta, acho que é um pouco cedo para respostas ainda, seria melhor pedir detalhes ao AP primeiro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, mencionei ao final que pode ser alguma mudança de endereço do servidor do repositório. Não tenho outra ideia do que possa ser além disto.